# How to get hours difference between two dates

Tags: time, go

I'm working for first time on Go, in this case i have a string on UTC format, I would like to know, how can I get the difference in hours between my date and the time now.
This is my current string

```
v := "2014-05-03 20:57 UTC"
```

Comment: In case someone needs difference between 2 dates. In year,days,hours format.[example code ](https://play.golang.org/p/a6nuFaY0Q1Y). Layout can be anything.I have chosen RFC3339.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Use [time.Parse](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse) and [time.Since](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Since):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

const (
    // See http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse
    timeFormat = "2006-01-02 15:04 MST"
)

func main() {
    v := "2014-05-03 20:57 UTC"
    then, err := time.Parse(timeFormat, v)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    duration := time.Since(then)
    fmt.Println(duration.Hours())
}
```

Comment: I am not sure why the output is negative which looks to be wrong .

Comment: @James most likely the time is in the future or the system clock is wrong.

Comment: my bad i was checking in goplayground and In the playground the time begins at 2009-11-10 23:00:00 UTC (determining the significance of this date is an exercise for the reader). This makes it easier to cache programs by giving them deterministic output.

Answer (score 43):

Have a look at the [time package](http://godoc.org/time).

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"

func main() {
    a, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02 15:04 MST", "2014-05-03 20:57 UTC")
    if err != nil {
        // ...
        return
    }

    delta := time.Now().Sub(a)
    fmt.Println(delta.Hours())
}
```

Comment: While `time.Since` actually uses `Sub` internally, I'd rather use `Since`. Less typing, better to read.